# How to Google Tag Manager DataLayer in Wordpress PHP Function

Tags: php, wordpress, google-tag-manager, custom-wordpress-pages

I've been trying to figure out how to make a dataLayer for the Order Confirmation page (Thankyou.php). I wanted to add the following function (via functions.php or Code Snippet) but it gives a fatal error when I try. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this?

I'm fairly new but trying to learn and I've been researching but can't find the answer, sorry if this may be a novice question. It gives a fatal error for the < in script so I thought maybe I wasn't supposed to have  in PHP but when I remove that then I get a fatal error for unexpected { on same line:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'checkout_datalayer' );

function checkout_datalayer( $order_id ) {

<script>
      dataLayer.push({
          'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': '<?php echo $order->get_order_currency(); ?>',
            'purchase': {
              'actionField':{
                'id': '<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>',
                'affiliation': 'Website',
                'revenue': <?php echo number_format($order->get_total(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
                'shipping': <?php echo number_format($order->calculate_shipping(), 2, ".", ""); ?>,
                <?php if($order->get_used_coupons()): ?>
                    'coupon': '<?php echo implode("-", $order->get_used_coupons()); ?>'
                <?php endif; ?>

              },
              'products': [
                  <?php
                    foreach($order->get_items() as $key => $item):
                      $product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
                  ?>
                      {
                        'name': '<?php echo $item['name']; ?>',
                        'id': '<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>',
                        'price': '<?php echo number_format($order->get_line_subtotal($item), 2, ".", ""); ?>',
                        'brand': 'Brand',
                        'quantity': <?php echo $item['qty']; ?>
                      },
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                ]
            }
          }
      });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone interested, I figured out the issue I believe. It was assuming the entire thing was PHP and the only way to stop that was to add `?>` before the `<script>` and `<?php` after the `</script>`.

Comment: Thank you! After pulling my hair out and biting my nails off your simple answer did the trick! I owe you a beer or six :-)